# SQL check if row contains set of values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row, multiple-columns

I have a Database like the following: 
[image]

I now want to check each row in this table if it contains a set of data. like so: I want to query for the following letters: `A, B`
this should return the following rows: `res1, res4`
this is because both `res1` and `res4` contain the values `A` and `B` in one of the columns

this logic also applies in this case:
and if i would only query for the letter `B` the query must return the following rows: `res1, res2, res4`

So what i want to happen is that the query checks the columns `valsx, valsy, valsz, valsq` if either one of these columns contains one of the queried values. And if all the queried values exist in the row (the four columns) then return the row.

How would i do this with SQL i have no idea. I tried 
`select * from table where valsx contains b or valsy contains b or valsz contains b or valsq contains b`

if anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where 'A' in (valsx, valsy, valsz, valsq) and
      'B' in (valsx, valsy, valsz, valsq);
```

Comment: nice that is what i needed thanks!

Comment: quick question where does `t.*` refer to?

Comment: @FutureCake . . . It refers to all columns in the `t` table defined in the `from` clause.

Comment: cant i then also just use `select * from` what would be the difference?

Comment: @FutureCake . . . The `t` qualifies the column references.  With only one table it is not needed.  But it is a good habit to qualify all column references.

Comment: ok makes sense thanks